# Incorrect bar position when 'bar width' is defined in axis unit with 'bar shift auto = 0'

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

When tweaking some axis options, I found this strange behaviour.
When setting both `bar width` and `bar shift auto` without units, the bar are positionned incorrectly.
There is no warning or error message in the log.

Is this really a bug, or do I miss something here ?

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepackage{times}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=7cm,bar shift auto=0pt]
        \addplot[ybar, bar width=1, fill=blue] coordinates {(10,5) (15,10) (5,15) (24,20) (30,25)};
        \addplot[ybar, bar width=1, fill=red]  coordinates {(10,5) (15,10) (5,15) (24,20) (30,25)};
        \node[anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs:0,1) {bar shift auto=0pt,bar width=1};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=7cm,bar shift auto=0]
        \addplot[ybar, bar width=1, fill=blue] coordinates {(10,5) (15,10) (5,15) (24,20) (30,25)};
        \addplot[ybar, bar width=1, fill=red]  coordinates {(10,5) (15,10) (5,15) (24,20) (30,25)};
        \node[anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs:0,1) {bar shift auto=0,bar width=1};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=7cm,bar shift auto=0pt]
        \addplot[ybar, bar width=5pt, fill=blue] coordinates {(10,5) (15,10) (5,15) (24,20) (30,25)};
        \addplot[ybar, bar width=5pt, fill=red]  coordinates {(10,5) (15,10) (5,15) (24,20) (30,25)};
        \node[anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs:0,1) {bar shift auto=0pt,bar width=5pt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[width=7cm,height=7cm,bar shift auto=0]
        \addplot[ybar, bar width=5pt, fill=blue] coordinates {(10,5) (15,10) (5,15) (24,20) (30,25)};
        \addplot[ybar, bar width=5pt, fill=red]  coordinates {(10,5) (15,10) (5,15) (24,20) (30,25)};
        \node[anchor=north west] at (rel axis cs:0,1) {bar shift auto=0,bar width=5pt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No problem, modifications are done

Comment: Generally I would say that `bar shift auto` expects a length. Thus I guess you are *lucky* when stating `0` works. When you *really* want to know if this is a bug I recommend adding a bug to the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/).

Comment: @StefanPinnow I do not agree that `bar shift auto` expects a length. It may expect a length, but the way it it used is not that specific. If you look at the `pgfplots manual` it is used to define the `bar shift` based on this expression `n·bar width+(n−1)·<shift for multiple plots>`, where `bar width` may not have a unit, hence my example. `bar width` should be `<dimension or unit>`, which is much more specific thant `<shift for multiple plots>` by the way.

Comment: @StefanPinnow Regarging the bug, my little experience here has taught me that something that seems to be a bug is often just a misunderstanding of the use of a functionnality. Asking first here seems about right in such situations.

Comment: Reading the related manual parts (again) you may be right. It is not explicitly written what a valid input is. The only thing that is clear is that a length *is* a valid input because of the default value of `2pt`. Thus, my suggestion with the Tracker still holds in case you question isn't answered here satisfyingly.

Comment: @StefanPinnow I added a tickect on the `pgfplots` tracker